# TemplateSyntaxError: Templates and static files

Tags: django

I have components for the website and they all work fine, for example I have a navbar.html and works flawlessly. However, I think the issue begins when I have a static file. I have another component called 'header.html' (which contains a profile picture) and SHOULD have loaded up a header in my index.html file. But it spits 'TemplateSyntaxError' and says that the issue is with the line code '{% static ... %}'.

[image]

My settings.py seems correct (see below). I also included 'django.contrib.staticfiles' and {% load static %} in the main index.html.

[image]

This is also the html part:

[image]

The structure of my project is as such:

- -myproject
- --base
- --myproject
- --static
- --staticfiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you load static on the template?

Add `{% load static %}` to the top of your html file

Comment: Ahhhhh that was it! I knew was something small but couldn't figure it out! Thank you very much!!!!